# Search for a hex pattern throughout a volume

Tags: data-recovery, block-device, hexdump

The inode table of my USB device was removed (/dev/sda). I am hoping to recover a file that contained a unique string which in hex format is:

"6d 61 79 32 30 32 30"

Is it possible to search throughout an entire partition for this hex patter? Are there clitools for this already? Or C libraries I could use?

Comment: Do you want to do something special to the string `may2020` once you find it? It would probably be possible to just use `grep` on the device otherwise. If this is a data recovery attempt, make sure that you work on an image of the device rather than on the device itself.

Comment: Hi Kusalananda, I created an image and wrote that to a disk. I found that the file format I am looking for has a special pattern using hexdump. So I thought I could find all these files using that hex pattern. Does grep work on special device files (i.e. /dev/sda)

Comment: Once you found the pattern in the disk image, what do you want to do with the information that the pattern was found on position 385943 within the disk image?

Comment: I would find the offset of that file and recreate it using `dd`.